# List all categories based on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

In wordpress I am using custom post types to filter out certain items. Those items have an associated category. What I would like to do is list all categories based on the post type.

### For example

```
Post type - education
Categories - k-12, higher education
```

If you notice above education is the custom post type. I have posts inside of that that are assigned to their respective categories. How could I go about listing all categories in a custom post type?

Comment: whats your custom taxonomy name (your custom post type's cat) ?

Comment: I just have a post type `education` and 2 categories that are assigned to posts within that custom post type. IE `k-12, higher education`

Comment: so you want to display all terms of a a custom taxonomy or list all these custom taxonomies check this url here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070898/i-want-to-display-custom-taxonomies-list-in-home-page-wordpress

Comment: All categories listed within my custom post type. Do I need to register a taxonomy to a custom post type? Everything I do seems to just spit out all categories instead of the ones within the custom post type.

Comment: You must understand what does custom post type and custom taxonomy mean.Taxonomies are categorizations of data but custom Post Types are really just custom data items.I didn't get exactly what you are looking to do.Where do you want to display terms, single page or on any template?If you check the above url in my previous comment its just a way to do.More info here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies